# Cannot integrate Azure Web App to Vnet

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I have Web App and SQL Server VM on Vnet running on Azure.  I would like to integrate Web App to virtual network.

I'm followings https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#managing-the-vnet-integrations

1) I created gateway subnet and gateway.

2) I opened "App Service->Networking->VNet integration->Setup->Virtual network is visible but it is gray!

What I need to do that I can connect Web App to Vnet?

Comment: Warning is "Gateway does not have point to site address"

Comment: Have you configured  your VPN gateway >settings> Point-to -site configuration >address pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple reasons that a VNet can be grayed out including:

•   the VNet is in another subscription that your account has access to

•   **the VNet does not have Point to Site enabled**

•   the VNet does not have a dynamic routing gateway

**According to your steps, This issue may caused by that  you might not configure a P2S address pool of your VPN gateway .**

I did a test in my lab, and finally I can integrate my Web App to the Vnet.
You should to check these two point as following images:

Your VPN ponit-to-site configuration: 
[image: p2s configuration]

Your VNet connected devices:
[image: your Vnet connected devices]

How to Enabling Point to Site in a Resource Manager VNet:

To configure a Resource Manager VNet with a gateway and Point to Site, you can use either PowerShell as documented here, [Configure a Point-to-Site connection to a virtual network using PowerShell](http://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-rm-ps/) or use the Azure portal as documented here, [Configure a Point-to-Site connection to a VNet using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal). The UI to perform this capability is not yet available. Note that you need to create certificates for the Point to Site configuration. This is automatically configured when you connect your WebApp to the VNet.